# Why is InputHidden readonly attribute not in JSF documentation?

Tags: jsf

I have recently encountered a case where I wanted to set the index value from `ui:repeat varStatus="v"` using `<h:inputHidden="#{v.index}/>`. If you try this and `execute` the component using AJAX you will get an exception that the property is not writeable. While looking around I found that `inputHidden` supports a `readonly="true"` attribute that does just that making the error go away.

Is there a reason why this is not in documentation? (i.e. special, passthrough, other)
Is it safe to use?

Comment: Just use `<input type="hidden">`? Why does it have to be a JSF component per se?

Comment: I don't have a good reason other than curiosity. I get that if I mark it as read only then there is no need to use JSF for it. On the other hand I can think of many use cases of playing with `readonly` using EL  and was curious why it isn't documented anywhere?

Comment: @BalusC JSF `inputHidden` can have validator and a label. Use case in a wizard where the user select a payment method which need additional data like bank account and user can open a dialog to save the account (independent of the current order). The `inputHidden` outside the dialog uses a dummy getter/empty setter which just returns true if the bank account was saved. The primefaces wizard automatically validates the input if user clicks next. Else we need in code to validate and preventing the next step and post message. Sadly the `inputHidden` does not allow readonly to omit the setter.

Answer (score 4):

After doing some digging [Core JavaServer Faces 3e](http://horstmann.com/corejsf/) had this to say :

> The h:inputHidden tag has the same attributes as the other input tags, except that it does not support the standard HTML and DHTML tags

So, the reason why `readonly` is not in the docs for `inputHidden` and also why it's not being rendered in your HTML is because `inputHidden` does not support it. This was also confirmed by Netbeans when I tried to add `readonly` as an attribute to `inputHidden`'(red squiggly lines with an error message). I was able to get that exception when I submitted a form with no `setter` defined for my bean property that was placed in `inputHidden`. Since `inputHidden` calls the `setter` when a form is submitted (for my case) and since none is defined in my code, it will of course throw that exception, namely:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /index.xhtml @14,56 value="#{bean.x}": The class 'Bean' does not have a writable property 'x'.
```

As for why it works when you do that I have no idea. Since you're worried about safety, I would suggest you do as BalusC says and simply use `<input type="hidden">` or you define a `setter` for that property. Don't use it like that.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I checked the generated HTML and it doesn't appear to be a pass-through attribute as it is not rendered on the HTML. The only two ways I can imagine for the setter not to be called would be if the html doesn't not include it inside the form(nothing rendered in html) or JSF to read the attribute and skip `setValue`. The reason why a setter is not available is that I am binding the `ui:repeat` `varStatus.index` which I do not control(no setter) and do not want to set. My key question is why this is nowhere to be found in the JSF documentation?

Comment: @johnd You mean [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2_MR1/docs/tlddocs/index.html) ? I don't know, but it seems only the docs only contain JSF specific attributes. The link I have on my answer shows all the HTML `input` attributes and `readonly` is there. I'm thinking JSF is simply simulating what `readonly` does by not calling the `setter` but you have to specify it on the JSF input component.

Comment: Yes, but the [JSF 2.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/) version. It appears to be in `inputText`, but not in `inputHidden` although it works fine for it. Not calling the setter is exactly what I wanted to do, but I don't know if it is safe to use as if it is not in these docs it might me deprecated or not implemented in eg. MyFaces

Comment: @johnd It does work though with `readonly = true`. This is so weird. Did you manage to find anything.

Comment: The reason why this works for mojarra is that the `HiddenRender` extends the `HtmlBasicRenderer` which is where the `readonly` is processed. I don't have Myfaces so I don't know if it works there. Also, I can see how this could have slipped in, but not being part of the documentation. I was using what BalusC suggested, but the question still stands: Is this attribute intended to function or is it a 'good' bug?

Comment: @johnd I don't know. File it I guess and see what they have to say. Besides, do you want to rely on a (potential) bug behavior ? What if if it gets scrapped, stuff will break. It's not documented so I would be skeptical. I couldn't find any bug reports for that also.

Answer (score -1):

So long time since this question started, however just FYI, this works:

```
<h:inputHidden id="compId" readonly="#{true}" value="#{myBean.attribute}" />
```

Comment: Please re-read the question. The OP already knew that. The OP already used it. The OP merely asked why it isn't documented and whether it's safe to use the undocumented attribute.